# is there anyway to make a synchronous ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am making a ajax call on of my view in MVC4.
code is :

```
 $.ajax({
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     method: 'GET',
     url: "Gateway/DB_Rola?count="+(n+1),
     data: things[n],
     success: function (Data) {
     var mera_obj = Data.key;
     document.getElementById("Param2").value = '(' + mera_obj.Response_Code + ' , ' + mera_obj.Response_Description + ')';
     },
     error: function () {
         alert("ERROR: can't connect to Server this time");
         return false;
    }
});
alert("call done for  "+(n));
```

when i make this call, ajax request is sent to URL and before the response, `alert` is executed which is outside the ajax. i want to wait for the response and then precede further. i mean synchronous ajax call.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "synchronous ajax call"? You most likely don't need it to be synchronous.

Comment: This has been answered many times

Comment: Please do some research before resorting to posting here.  This is a question easily answered by Google. or even jQuery.com

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Set the [`async`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) flag to false:

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    method: 'GET',
    async: false,
    ...
```

Comment: So, just out of curiosity...because I'm struggling to see the use of making a synchronous ajax call. What actually happens when you set this option to false? What happens when the response is received? Is the error/success handler evaluated before the code following the ajax call? For example, in the question asked by Marium...would the success handler execute before the alert (the one outside of the ajax method)?

Comment: If you set it to false, it essentially becomes a completely blocking expression; you can set a global variable, and update it upon done, then continue on line by line after the function ends with the new, updated global variable value. And no, the success handler would happen after the call is complete, and the alert subsequently after that.

Comment: Right, I was suspecting that's what'd happen. But, I'm still struggling to realize how I can benefit from this...I've never implemented or run into a scenario where I might have needed this behaviour. I can only imagine this setting would produce a horrible user experience, I would just do a full post back to the server. Anyway, thanks for your response mate

Comment: @Leo oh, no, I wouldn't exactly recommend it -- but there probably are some edge cases that it might need to be done, either for legacy purposes or if you're dealing with poor design to begin with.

Comment: @Leo yah r3mus is right . this statement holds the very next statement after the call until response is received from server. working perfectly...